# search most popular twitter accounts in specific country

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am trying to retrieve most popular twitter accounts from a specific country using tweepy API. I can not use location or coordinates, because not all the the accounts have shared that information. I checked user object attributes and they were empty. is there any other way to limit the users search to a country?? or even language?

Comment: basically you cant, except base on location they provided, the time zone, the location in the tweet (if any, rare cases), anything other than that is privacy and twitter should protect that kind of information. if you could find some way to get those information, you could make a lot of money by selling and suing twitter company. Just imagine if you see someone tweet they on a vacation, a sweet opportunity to rob their house, or...

Comment: thanks. what about limiting to a specific language? @PhongPhung

Comment: As Phong Phung said you won't be able to reach server-protected information, such as private tweets. You can get the html dump and use it with urllib2 and 3. You shouldn't limit  yourself to one single language - write this `#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the beginning of the script and itll work just fine with every language.

Comment: thanks, I will try this@MrYahli